# While loop to check character input

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop, character

I am trying to accept input from the user in the form of a character. I have that working but I need to check and make sure it is one of 6 characters (H, h, S, s, L, l). I have a while loop but as soon as add more than one character statement to it, the loop gives the error for every value that should be correct.

Here is the function:

```
    private static char getHighLow(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    System.out.println("High, Low, or Sevens (H/L/S): ");
    String choiceString = keyboard.next();

    char choice = choiceString.charAt(0);

    while (choice != 'H' || choice != 'h' || choice != 'L' || choice != 'l' || choice != 'S' || choice != 's')
    {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid entry.");
        System.out.println("High, Low, or Sevens (H/L/S): ");
        choiceString = keyboard.next();
    }

    return choice;

}
```

What is the best way to continue checking for multiple characters like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your logic: you should be connecting those tests with AND: `&&`:

```
while (choice != 'H' && choice != 'h' && choice != 'L' && ...
```

Furthermore `choice` is never being updated within the body of the loop, so it will never change. Duplicate the `choice = choiceString.charAt(0);` after you re-read `choiceString` within the loop.

Conceptually, you want to keep asking for input so long as the character *isn't H AND isn't L AND isn't S*.

Answer (score 4):

Use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
while (choice != 'H' && choice != 'h' && choice != 'L' && choice != 'l' && choice != 'S' && choice != 's')
```

This can be simplified by converting to lower case first.

```
choice = Character.toLowerCase(choice);

while (choice != 'h' && choice != 'l' && choice != 's')
```

Comment: Perfect that did it. I think I'm getting the logic for this now, but correct me if I'm wrong. I don't want to enter that loop unless none of those characters are entered. So it checks each character and fails because every single AND needs to be true?

Answer (score 2):

You never update `choice` in your `while` loop:

Just add this line at the end of your loop:

```
choice = choiceString.charAt(0);
```

Moreover you should check with `&&` rather than `||`.