# Logic Error in Java For-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make the loop continue to execute here until the user types the letter S at the keyboard. It seems to be giving three outputs instead of one for each iteration. What am I doing wrong here;

```
// Loop until an S is typed

public class ForTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws java.io.IOException {

        int i;

        System.out.println("Type S to stop.");

        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) 
//          System.out.println("print");
            System.out.println("Pass # " + i);
//          System.out.println("print");


    }

}
```

Output coming up is if I press 'a':

```
Type S to stop.
a
Pass # 0
Pass # 1
Pass # 2
```

Comment: There are 3 characters in `a\r\n`. You're using Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898455/while-loop-to-check-character-input

Comment: it doesn't print that just tried but when I enter anything it prints twice means the iteration runs twice

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo and you're using a Mac?

Comment: nope, i am on win

Comment: it prints the value twice because of IO delay, till the value is processed, it's printing 2 values

Comment: What shell are you using to run the program @DanyalS?

Comment: I am running over it an IDE  known as intellij using jdk 1.8

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments and answers. I read about the inputstream flaws last week and it has just been highlighted with this code. I am fairly new to Java so just trying to familiarize myself with it.

Answer (score 2):

The [InputStream.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read) method block until the end of input which is on a Windows OS the control characters CR LF (\r\n).

This explains why you get 3 characters as a result.

See for yourself :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

    int i;

    System.out.println("Type S to stop.");

    char c = (char) 0;
    for (i = 0; c != 'S'; i++) {
        c = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("Pass # " + i);
        System.out.println("char intValue : " + (int) c);
    }
}
```

Suggested read : 
[Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console)

Comment: This code works. I like the way you introduced the (int)c to make me follow the trail. Now I checked CR LF on the ascii table and I see they are printed each time hence the three outputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

System.in will use BufferedInputSteam to read the input from console bit by bit (including the line break, etc). In Mac system, I get 2 bits whenever i gave a single digit input.

Use Scanner and read all the bytes and convert as String.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid reading input in that way, use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead.
You can reach your goal with this code:

```
    int i = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type S to stop.");
    while( !scan.next().equals("S")) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Pass # "+i);
    }
```

Comment: You still need to consume the linebreaks - this doesn't solve anything.

Comment: I tried it and it works. I had to import Scanner. Thanks